# simplexml_load_file works fine at server 5 min, then suddenly stops

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am running a code on website, it works like 5 min, then suddenly stopping.

```
$use_errors = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
libxml_clear_errors();
libxml_use_internal_errors($use_errors);
echo $xml->ratio;
```

On my webserver the function allow_url_fopen is enable, php version is 5.5

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Here are to many possibilities. But if you're loading data for 5 min you might run into memory problems.

Comment: How do you know it is working for 5 minutes and then "suddenly" stopping? Do you get some kind of progress report?

Comment: Its working like 10-15 minutes, then breaks after sometime its alive again and so on